# Embbed Flash video in MS Word (2003 or 2007) document

Tags: video, microsoft-word, flash

How would you go about embedding a Flash video into a MS Word document?

- Embedding the .flv and the player
  into a Word document
- Embedding just
  the player and remotely linking to
  the .flv

Open source or fee-ware solutions are acceptable.

**UPDATED:**

I see that people are more interested in making stray and unhelpful comments rather than providing some help.

However, in the spirit of disclosure and clarification the next paragraph contains the **“WHY”**.

I am writing a presentation for business team members at my job.  Ninety percent of the document will be prose in MS Word.  For illustrative purposes I will be using [Balsamiq mockups for Desktop](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/desktop) to layout the proposed UI.  Balsamiq mockups has a presentation mode, however this mode is not exportable into a standalone format.  My plan is to use Camstudio to capture the screen transitions of the Balsamiq presentation mode as a flash video.  Why flash video?  It also makes it easy for other business people types to see it in a web browser if necessary at a later time (e.g. Wiki).  And finally embed the .flv file into the Word document rather than a **“CLICK HERE”** link, in an effort to try to have a clean and encapsulated look to the document.

Comment: I'm feeling sorry for the unfortunate people that have to watch videos in Word :(

Answer (score 2):

Word does not allow you to import .FLV videos. Your only option is to save the video to a word-friendly format (such as .avi) and .flv just for the website.

Answer (score 1):

I found this short [tutorial](http://www.video-tutes.com/player/player.php?id=1585&T_id=5a) on playing flash animations in a word document. You may be able to modify it to play a flash video in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Although I understand your requirement, embedding either will drastically increase the size of the document. I would honestly do an external link with screen-shots only in the document.

I can't imagine that the player itself can be embedded at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way that you can embed the Flash Player within a Word document.  However, Word does provide the option of embedding an AVI file, so that may be the route to go.