# Is it possible to embed a video in a MS Word document?

Tags: video, microsoft-word

I want to find out if it's possible to embed a video file in a MS Word document? I mean not to have a link to a file on a file system, but actually put a video file into a document file.

I need to know if it's possible to have a single document, which can have an embedded video and can be viewed on another machine. If it's not possible, I would like to get some explanations about it.

Comment: Related: [Embed Flash video in MS Word (2003 or 2007) document](http://superuser.com/questions/2964/embbed-flash-video-in-ms-word-2003-or-2007-document?rq=1)

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can insert multiple sources of video into a word doc.  Here is a tutorial from microsoft how just how to do that.  Hope this helps.

[How to video and MSword](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-a-movie-HP005190177.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. And if I save this doc as an rtf document, will the video still be available?